# Prevent Recyclerview from resizing when keyboard is visible

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Most questions are asking about how to make the recyclerview resize when the soft keyboard is visible, although I want the opposite. The recyclerview already resizes when KB is visible, I tried removing `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`but the same happens, the recyclerview always resizes. How can I achieve what I want (programmatically is preferred)

Comment: Try using `adjustNothing`

Comment: Not working also.

Comment: then you have a problem elsewhere - docs definition : `adjustNothing :  Don't resize or pan the window to make room for the soft input area; the window is never adjusted for it.`

Comment: I have the same problem. When vertical recyclerview added to my view all  adjustNothing  not works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try stating an explicit size for the window your RecyclerView is embedded in, for example if it's in a AlertDialog, following AlertDialog.show() you add:

alertDialog.window!!.setLayout(width: 1000, height: 1300)